# Подчеркнуть текст в Android пунктирной линией?

Tags: android, html, xml

Есть решение как подчеркнуть обычной линией

```
String htmlTaggedString  = "<u>адреса</u>";
    Spanned textSpan  =  android.text.Html.fromHtml(htmlTaggedString);
    tv_adr.setText(textSpan);
```

Но тэга пунктирного подчеркивания в HTML нет и это вызывает сложности в решении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вот это рабочий ответ.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:dashGap="10px"
                android:dashWidth="10px"
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ababb2" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

**dashed.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" >

    <stroke
        android:dashGap="2dip"
        android:dashWidth="2dip"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />

    <size android:width="60dp"
          android:height="6dp"/>

</shape>
```

затем

```
android:drawableBottom="@drawable/dashed"
```

[image]

Comment: У меня сплошной линией, текст подчеркивается.

Comment: Не рабочий этот ответ.

Comment: Умные здесь все) http://stackoverflow.com/a/18508609/5698345

Comment: @СергейГрушин, что именно вас смутило?